# Data structure for tiled map

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I want to make an infinite tiled map, from `(-max_int,-max_int)` until `(max_int,max_int)`, so I'm gonna make a basic structure: `chunk`, each `chunk` contain `char tiles[w][h]` and also it `int x, y` coordinates, so for example `h=w=10` so `tile(15,5)` is in `chunk(1,0)` on `(5,5) coordinate`, and `tile(-25,-17)` is in `chunk(-3,-2)`on`(5,3)` and so on. Now there can be any amount of chunks and I need to store them and easy access them in `O(logn)` or better ( `O(1)` if possible.. but it's not.. ). It should be easy to: add, ??remove??(not must) and find. So what data structure should I use?

Comment: This is difficult to follow. Perhaps you could provide a struct/class and a formula to convert from chunk, to tile to coordinate.

Comment: It's just a bunch of objects with x, y coordinates(chunks) and now I need to store them and easy access them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read into KD-tree or Quad-tree (the 2d variant of Octree). Both of these might be a big help here.

Comment: quad tree - should be a const size square... not fit.
kd-tree - what if I have only 10 chunks and all with same x??.

Comment: Depends on your construction algorithm for the kd-tree, but a common one is to split the largest dimension, so in the case of all boxes being on the same x-plane, you would always split on y, which should still keep your access times low. So in other words, if you don't force a kd-tree to rotate splitting planes and keep it adaptive, this is the exact problem it tries to solve.

Comment: what if there are all close to each other isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Basically, there are a few options you have. A point based kd-tree will be your silver bullet if the regions are all the same size (within the tree), and they all would fit into a regular grid, because you can compute the storage point from anywhere within a region. If, for some reason, the regions can overlap, you can also check out the BIH-tree because it is designed to handle that a little better. Regions being close don't matter to the kd-tree, it is adaptive.

Comment: What's wrong with 10 chunk on same `x`?... That can twice amount of levels - that's all. If you care you can do some kind of balancing with help of extra info in your nodes (amount of points in whole branch and dimension to split).

Comment: @ony The most efficient way to build the tree in the case of all of the nodes on the same x would be to sort all chunks by their y, and recursively insert the center of the sub-arrays (think reverse binary search), each time declaring the splitting plane to be along the y-axis, so that you essentially end up with a balanced bst. This is a valid kd-insertion algorithm if you decide to always split a node based on its longest dimension (y every time in this case), and it doesn't waste depth nodes.

Comment: @Mranz what you say is true for constant data, but as I understand Vlad wants dynamic structure (add/remove), so optimizing the tree during insertion and removing of chunks is important, I guess.

Comment: KD-tree's and BIH-tree's are awesome forms of real time spatial data structures because their construction time is lightning fast. I suppose another option is the BVH, probably the most used physics engine tree.

Answer (score 0):

So all your space is splited into chunks (rectangular clusters). Generally problem is storing data in sparse (since clusters already implemented) matrix. Why not to use two-level dictionary-like containers?.. I.e. rb-tree by row index where value is rb-tree by column index. Or if you are lucky you can use hashes to get your O(1). In both cases if you can't find row you allocate it in container and create new container as value but initially with only single chunk. Of course allocating new chunk on existing row will be a bit faster than on new one and I guess that's the only issue with this approach.

Comment: This would work, but the memory cost could be massive. They are better spatial data structures for these types of problems.